# TypeError: string indices must be integer while retrieving a data from google sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

**TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Background information

Trying to retrieve an information from google sheet. Please help not sure what I'm missing here,
Returns the spreadsheet at the given ID. The caller must specify the spreadsheet ID.
By default, data within grids will not be returned. You can include grid data one of two ways

Specify a field mask listing your desired fields using the fields URL parameter
Set the includeGridData URL parameter too true. If a field mask is set, the includeGridData parameter is ignored For large spreadsheets, it is recommended to retrieve only the specific fields of the spreadsheet that you want.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import os.path
import pymssql
import pickle
import get_sec
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"]

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = "spread_sheet_id"
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = "sample!A:E"
credentials = get_sec("matrix_metrics")
with open('credentials.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(credentials, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

f = open("credentials.json", "r")
print(f.read())

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                "credentials.json", SCOPES
            )
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build("sheets", "v4", credentials=creds)

    # Call the Sheets API
    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = (
        sheet.values()
        .get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME)
        .execute()
    )
    values = result.get("values", [])

    if not values:
        print("No data found.")
    else:
        print("Major")
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing its not able to decode credentials.json

output of credentials.json looks something like this [Secret are redacted] ->

```
"{\"installed\":{\"client_xx\":\"[redacted]",\"project_id\":\"xxx\",\"auth_uri\":\"https://accounts.google.com/xxx",\"token_uri\":\"https://xxxxx.googlexxx.com/xxx\",\"xxx_cert_url\":\"https://www.googlexxx.com/xxxx/xx/certs\",\"client_sec\":\"xxxxxxxxxxxxx\",\"redirect_uris\":[\"xxxxxxxxxxx\",\"http://localhost\"]}}
```

*Stack trace*

````
  File "data.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()
  File "data.py", line 41, in main
    "credentials.json", SCOPES
  File "/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 199, in from_client_secrets_file
    return cls.from_client_config(client_config, scopes=scopes, **kwargs)
  File "/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 168, in from_client_config
    client_config, scopes, **kwargs))
  File "/google_auth_oauthlib/helpers.py", line 61, in session_from_client_config
    config = client_config['installed']
TypeError: string indices must be integers```
````

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace, we don't know where the error is happening.

Comment: Yes, can you please include all the error messages you saw, one of those will show what line fails. Did the quickstart work without modification?

Comment: @joao added a stack trace any help here is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use json.dumps() instead of json.dump() - it's more human readable.

Comment: Just in case - did you follow the exact steps in the quickstart? Your code looks almost identical but it seems that you cut out parts of it. Try just going through the steps exactly and getting authorization working before adding in other functionality.

Comment: Here you need to have token.pickle file present

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted includes the call to `from_client_secrets_file()`, but the
stack trace shows that the error occurs 3 functions calls down, so we don't
actually see the code where the error is.

However, the TypeError tells us that `client_config` is a string, but the code
obviously expected it to be a dictionary with a 'installed' key.

This is exactly the output of credentials.json as you showed it, so when
calling `from_client_secrets_file()`, instead of passing in the
"credentials.json" string (the filename) you should pass in the **contents** of the
credentials.json file, i.e. read the file, decode the json object into a python
dict, and pass that dict in.